# flutter uploading image to backed from flutter error 401

Tags: flutter

Future uploadFile() async {
// file picker를 통해 파일 선택

```
  final filePath = _image!.path;

  // 파일 경로를 통해 formData 생성
  var dio = ref.read(dioProvider);
  var formData = FormData.fromMap({
    'file' : await MultipartFile.fromFile(filePath!)
  });

  dio.options.headers.addAll({
    'accessToken': 'true',
  });
  // 업로드 요청
  final response = await dio.post("http://$ip/s3/upload", data: formData,options: Options(
    contentType: 'multipart/form-data'
  ));
  _downloadUrl = response.data;
  print(response.statusCode.toString() + "hihi");
```

}

```
error : [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [401]
```

I'm using a spring server and if I send an image upload request to the above code, I keep getting 401 errors. Is there a solution?

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [401]
```

Answer (score 0):

An http 401 errors occurs when you are not authenticated. Does your server require some sort of a JWT token, if so i suggest authenticating and  adding it to your header like this:

```
  dio.options.headers.addAll({
    'Authorization": "Bearer <your token here>'
  });
```